# Impossible to add files on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I tried many things and watched vids and tutorials but nothing could help. I'm just trying to add an existing project on BitBucket, and observed all steps described. However I keep having the same error :

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/projet-gsb-php.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I even deleted my git local folder and followed those steps :

```
C:\wamp\www>cd GSB_AppliMVC
C:\wamp\www\GSB_AppliMVC>git init
(...)
C:\wamp\www\GSB_AppliMVC>git add -A
C:\wamp\www\GSB_AppliMVC>git commit -m "Initial Commit"
C:\wamp\www\GSB_AppliMVC>git remote add origin https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/projet-gsb-php.git
C:\wamp\www\GSB_AppliMVC>git push -u origin master
(ERROR MESSAGE ABOVE)
```

I tried to push it on GitLab instead but have exactly the same problem. So there must be something obvious but I really don't know what.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. You have to pull before you can push.

Comment: I tried to pull like this
 git pull https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/projet-gsb-php.git
And to push after but nothing is changed
And my remote repository is empty

Comment: `git pull -f origin master && git push`

Comment: @Valeriy I just tried with git pull-f before pushing but : with "git push" after, I have this message ;     git push --set-upstream origin master / and if I try to do this I keep having the same error message again...

Comment: Is your repository on BitBucket non-empty?

Comment: It is empty except the initial commit by BitBucket with the readme file

Comment: is your exiting project having a `.git` directory?

Comment: yes ! I even deleted the old one to recreate a new one but nothing changed

Comment: Well, go to `C:\wamp\www` and do `git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/projet-gsb-php.git`. Then copy files you need from `GSB_AppliMVC` to `projet-gsb-php` , commit changes and push it

Comment: @Valeriy this is what i ended up doing and it seems to work :) thank you

Comment: @SidGabriel, Well, please mark my answer as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `C:\wamp\www`
2. Do `git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/projet-gsb-php.git`
3. Copy files you need from `GSB_AppliMVC` to `projet-gsb-php`
4. Push it